# Is it possible to have a scenario outline table with empty values?

Tags: python, bdd, gherkin

Scenaio Outline: Blah de blah
  When I enter  and  on the input field
  Then Everything is good

Examples:
  | a | b |
  | 1 | 2 |
  |    | 3 |

The above scenario throws the following error in BBD Behave
Test undefined
Please define test

I am not sure how I can come around this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Custom Type Conversions` described in `https://pypi.org/project/parse/`

```
import parse

from behave import given, register_type


@parse.with_pattern(r'.*')
def parse_nullable_string(text):
    return text


register_type(NullableString=parse_nullable_string)

@given('params "{a:NullableString}" and "{b:NullableString}"'
def set_params(context, a, b):
  # a or b will be empty if they are blank in the Examples
  context.a = a
  context.b = b
```

Now the feature file could look like this,

```
Given params "<a>" and "<b>"
# Rest of the steps
Examples:
 | a | b |
 | 1 | 2 |
 |   | 3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to use empty table cells (as in your example, not using "" or something) if you can go without explicitly mentioning your parameters in your given/when/then steps.

In your example, that would mean that you must not write your step definitions like this

```
Given two parameters <a> and <b>
...

@given('two parameters {a} and {b}
def step(context, a, b):
  # test something with a and b
```

but rather like this:

```
Given two parameters a and b # <-- note the missing angle brackets
...

@given('two parameters a and b') <-- note the missing curly brackets
def step(context): # <-- note the missing function arguments for a and b
  # ...
```

Now, in order to access the current table row, you can use `context.active_outline` [(which is a bit hidden in the appendix of the documentation)](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/context_attributes.html).

`context.active_outline` returns a [behave.model.row](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#behave.model.Row) object which can be accessed in the following ways:

- `context.active_outline.headings` returns a list of the table headers, no matter what the currently iterated row is (*a* and *b* in the example from the question )
- `context.active_outline.cells` returns a list of the cell values for the currently iterated row (*1*, *2* and '' (empty string that can be tested with `if not...`), *3* in the example from the question)
- index-based access like `context.active_outline[0]` returns the cell value from the first column (no matter the heading) etc.
- named-based access like `context.active_outline['a']` returns the cell value for the column with the *a* header, no matter its index

As `context.active_outline.headings` and `context.active_outline.cells` return lists, one can also do useful stuff like `for heading, cell in zip(context.active_outline.headings, context.active_outline.cells)` to iterate over the heading-value pairs etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do it.  But you can use either an empty string or a placeholder value (e.g. 'N/A') that you can look out for in your step definitions.