# behave empty values in the example table

Tags: python, python-behave

I want to insert empty values in the example table for rest API automation. I have used the following code found in a different question at stack  overflow but using this, If I input blank value in the example table, its captured as "" in the input json file like below which is not
correct.

Actual data coming in the input json

```
"\"\""
```

My expected data in the input json which is by default there in the request json body

```
""
```

Scenario example table

```
| a    | b      |
| 5    | 33     |
| a    |        |
|      | abc    |
```

Code

```
import parse

from behave import given, register_type


@parse.with_pattern(r'.*')
def parse_nullable_string(text):
    return text


register_type(NullableString=parse_nullable_string)

@given('params "{a:NullableString}" and "{b:NullableString}"'
def set_params(context, a, b):
  # a or b will be empty if they are blank in the Examples
  context.a = a
  context.b = b
```

Comment: It may be useful to link your reference StackOverflow question.  This also looks like you may be either missing escape characters (typically \ in python), or have added an extra set. Please check then length of the returned string and specify what length of string you're expecting.  It's not clear to me that this is a real difference, rather than a difference in output formatting.

Comment: As per your advise, please find below the link of the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298550/is-it-possible-to-have-a-scenario-outline-table-with-empty-values

Comment: I want to have output like  "a": "" in the input json request body, but after using the above code and example table, I am having output like  "a": "\"\"", in the input json request body.

Comment: I tried out your code, building a list of the example rows then doing a `json.dumps` . The output json string looks good to me `[["5", "33"], ["a", ""], ["", "abc"]]`

Comment: I have not used json.dumps because I have inputted the request body as a json, not a string and when I run the API, it takes the value as "" in the actual test case instead of blank or null value